# save retina image in document folder increase image resolution and size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have retina image in document folder and need to redraw and save again. I had done something like.

```
NSLog(@"%f",[UIScreen mainScreen].scale); // Scale Factor : 2.000000
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(imgView.image.size));  // {4288, 2848} size : 2.6 MB
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
        [imgView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.image.size.width, imgView.image.size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
        UIImage *  image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(image.size)); // {4288, 2848} size : 2.6 MB

        NSString *path = [DOCUMENTPATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image@2x.jpg"];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:true];   // {8576, 5696} size : 21.2 MB
```

**Problem :**  When I save image in document folder image save with double resolution and more size of actual image

What's the best way to save image?

Comment: Of course the final image size (in pixels) is twice the width and height of the image size (in points) since the scale is 2.

Comment: How can i keep the same

Comment: You don't. Why do you want to? If you want it to be a `@2x` image, then its size in pixels is, by definition, twice the size as the size in points.

Comment: Listen, what I want is I have retina image with retina dimension in document folder. I want to edit and save image as same dimension

Comment: The code you posted is doing what you want. There is no problem. `UIImage` is measured in points. A `@2x` retina image will have twice as many pixels as points. A `@3x` retina image will have three times as many pixels as points.

Comment: I understood your point. Its doubles pixels points. what should i do make scale factor 1.0 ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale) in my case

Comment: If you want the pixels to match the points, pass `1` for the scale in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: @rmaddy It will be no effect on quality of image..?

Comment: @rmaddy Its save in same dimension but size of image is increased upto 800%. before it was 2.1 MB and after saving its now 17.2 MB